# Call function on button click event

Tags: vb.net

How do I call this vb.net function on the button click event?

```
Private Sub GridView_UDGReport_DataBound1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView1.DataBound

    For rowIndex As Integer = GridView_UDGReport.Rows.Count - 2 To 0 Step -1
        Dim gviewRow As GridViewRow = GridView_UDGReport.Rows(rowIndex)
        Dim gviewPreviousRow As GridViewRow = GridView_UDGReport.Rows(rowIndex + 1)
        For cellCount As Integer = 0 To gviewRow.Cells.Count - 1
            If gviewRow.Cells(cellCount).Text = gviewPreviousRow.Cells(cellCount).Text Then
                If gviewPreviousRow.Cells(cellCount).RowSpan < 2 Then
                    gviewRow.Cells(cellCount).RowSpan = 2
                Else
                    gviewRow.Cells(cellCount).RowSpan = gviewPreviousRow.Cells(cellCount).RowSpan + 1
                End If
                gviewPreviousRow.Cells(cellCount).Visible = False
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: _DataBound1 ?? question is not clear enough

Comment: I want to call this function GridView_UDGReport_DataBound1in the button click event...how should I call this function...generally we call by GridView_UDGReport_DataBound1()....but its throwing an error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append the first line so that the sub handles more than one event, as follows:

```
Private Sub GridView_UDGReport_DataBound1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GridView1.DataBound, Button1.Click
```

Alternatively, if you need your Click event to run some other code *in addition to calling this sub*, do this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'do something
    GridView_UDGReport_DataBound1(sender, e)
    'do something else
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using the parameters anyways, you can simply call the method with `Nothing` as parameter.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    GridView_UDGReport_DataBound1(Nothing, Nothing)
End Sub
```

Comment: how about `GridView_UDGReport.Rebind`?

Comment: No.. You can't do that. That is the name of event. You need to call the Method.